# Making a table of hex representations in Swift with compact code

Tags: swift

In C# one can write the following one line to make an array of all the hex strings representing the values from 0 to 255:

```cs
using System.Linq;
static string[] HexTbl = Enumerable.Range(0, 256).Select(v => v.ToString("X2")).ToArray();
```

Is there a similarly compact way to do this in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. The approach is the same: map each number in the range 
0 ... 255 to a string using a hex format:

```
let hexTable = (0 ..< 256).map { v in String(format: "%02X", v) }
```

or slightly shorter:

```
let hexTable = (0 ..< 256).map { String(format: "%02X", $0) }
```

Result:

```
["00", "01", "02", ..., "FD", "FE", "FF"]
```